# Does parbox has any conflict with the loop in algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I start to draw an algorithm using the algorithm package. And, I meet the problem that I can't well indent the parbox block which includes the loop, and it seems the parbox still effect the later parts:

My code is:

```
\documentclass[twoside, onecolumn, 11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\Inputs}[1]{%
\State \textbf{Inputs:}
\Statex \hspace*{\algorithmicindent}\parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright #1}
}
\algnewcommand{\Outputs}[1]{%
\State \textbf{Outputs:}
\Statex \hspace*{\algorithmicindent}\parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright #1}
}
\algnewcommand{\Compute}[1]{%
\State \textbf{Compute:}
\hspace*{\algorithmicindent}\parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright #1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Inputs{$X$}
    \Compute{
      \For{i = 0 to I}
        \State do sth in the loop
      \EndFor
    }
    \Outputs{$Y$}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and I got this:
[image]

I got a strange large indent of the content of Compute, and the Output is also with a indent seems effected by the parbox. How chould I well arrange this algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please complete your  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that it compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want to use parboxes at all, as it is not the way `algorithmicx` intends for you to do this. Indeed, `algorithmicx` lets you define new blocks for precisely this use. The parbox implementation (if you can get it to work) will have other unintended consequences as well, like indenting line numbers.

Instead, use `algorithmicx`'s block definition syntax. It does take a bit of slogging through the manual to understand. I think it's simplest just to use the meta-block-definer `\algdef` rather than trying to figure out which of the derived commands matches your desired use case (there are a lot of them!).

```
\documentclass[twoside, onecolumn, 11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SnEL}{Inputs}{EndInputs}{1}{\textbf{Inputs:} \State}
\algdef{SnEL}{Outputs}{EndOutputs}{1}{\textbf{Outputs:} \State}
\algdef{SnEl}{Compute}{EndCompute}{\textbf{Compute:}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Inputs $X$
    \Compute
      \For{$i = 0$ to $I$}
        \State do $s$th in the loop
      \EndFor
    \EndCompute
    \Outputs $Y$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

You might also consider redefining `\For` like on page 11 of the manual to get nicer formatting.

[image]

Comment: I added a picture of the nice result. The package warns `algdef: 'N' obsoloted, use 'nE'` (*sic*); can you do something about it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helps! As I am still not familiar with this package.

Comment: Okay, I've changed the `N` flags to `nE`, and that seems to get rid of the warning. I don't see `nE` documented though, so I don't know what's actually changed.